# C++ friend Operator<<(ostream os, obj objName)

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I have a question concerning the operator<< overload. I need to use one in my homework to return the content of a vector. I think that my operator method works, however I have completely no idea how to call it in another class.

Here's my operator in my ColonneCartes.cpp class:

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream & os, const ColonneCartes & p_colonneCartes)
{
     for (int i = 0; i < myVector.size(); i++)
     {
          os << myVector.at(i).getValue();
     }

     return os;
};
```

I'm trying to call it from another class to show it in the console and I didn't find out how to do it yet.

My second question is about returning in my operator the content of a vector object and I wanted to know if there's a another way than using a loop like this one to return the content?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: How do you `call it from another class to show it in the console`? Relevant code would be useful.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve What isn't working? What do you expect it should do? The calls to `myVector` should probably be `p_colonneCartes.myVector`.

Comment: I'm sorry I wasn't clear, forget it André answered it, I thought that it was used like a function, but actually it's not. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The console you are refering to is called standard output (*stdout*). In C++, using streams to output to the *stdout*, you should use the `std::cout` object from `iostream` header.

Suppose you have a `colonneCartes` object of type `ColonneCartes`, then, in order to output its `myVector` to *stdout*, write:

```
#include <iostream>
...
std::cout << colonneCartes;
```

The `operator<<` you wrote is what enables objects of type `ColonneCartes` to be used after the `<<`.

Comment: Oh okay I think I get it now. It's not used like a function, it's something that will be called automatically when using "<<". Thanks!